# Write contents to file -fs.writeFileSync - in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

**My Query**

How to write some contents to a file that would support in Browser

**What I have tried**

I managed the fs.readFileSync to work in browser using `brfs`

This bundled an output that manipulated the fileRead and added\replaced back with the actual data from the file.

But after processing the file content I need to write the file with another name.
For this I have the below statement

```
fileStream.writeFileSync(fileName, doc);
```

But the above fileStream doesn't get manipulated with brfs (only `fileStream.readFileSync('file')` gets updated with brfs

Please help me on writing back the file for browser

**Update**

I am completely new to NodeJS. Below I have placed the code - method name `ProcessFile` - which is working fine.
But when I use this method to execute the functionality on the browser am getting issues.

When I execute the the command `browserify -t brfs main.js -o bundle.js` 
in the bundle.js  , the method `ProcessFile`(placed below) gets transformed as below :

1. the statement marked below as STT_FS is removed
2. the statement marked as STT_FS_READ has some buffer binary data that should have been read from the given file
3. But statement marked as STT_FS_WRITE stays as it

B'coz of transformation #1 & #2 above, the error (object fs not supported ) gets resolved

-#3 still throws an error (SCRIPT5009: 'fileStream' is undefined)

The functionality of below method `ProcessFile` :

1. It reads a SVG document,
2. fills\shades the image in the file with a specified color\mode ==> stream
3. Writes the new content (stream) to another file and saves it in a location

   **The Code**

---

```
function ProcessFile(filePath,targetColor,fillColorMode)
{
    var fileStream = require('fs'); //STT_FS
    var xmldoc = require('xmldoc');
    var stringMethods = require('string');
    // Load the svg File from the givenfile path.
    var filePathStr = fileStream.readFileSync('E:\\NodeJS\\macPump.svg').toString();//STT_FS_READ
    //convert svg file to xml document
    var doc = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(filePathStr);
    //Collect the Groups from base SVG File
    var groupNodes = doc.childrenNamed('g');
    var sourceAttr ;
    var fillAttr;
    //If the groups  are not available in svg file,  then set all elements as children
    if(groupNodes.length===0) { groupNodes=doc.children; }
    //if target color mode is hollow then set target color to transparent
    if(fillColorMode.toLowerCase()==="hollow") {targetColor='transparent';}
   //iterate each groupNodes element here to change the color
   for (var groupCount = 0; j = groupNodes.length, groupCount < j; groupCount++) 
   {
     var styleElement =groupNodes[groupCount].children;
     //if the groupNodes element does not contains sub node then get the style attribute value directly .
     if(styleElement.length===0)
     {
         styleElement=groupNodes[groupCount];
         fillAttr=styleElement.attr['style'];
         if(fillColorMode.toLowerCase()!=="original")
         {
                // get updated target color here for basic type svg files
                styleElement.attr['style']=GetFillColor(fillAttr,targetColor,fillColorMode);
         }
     }//end of if
     else
     {
        for(var styleCount=0; k=styleElement.length,styleCount<k;styleCount++)
        {
            fillAttr=styleElement[styleCount].attr['fill'];

           if(fillColorMode.toLowerCase()!=="original")
            {
                    // get fill element color here
                   var fillElementColor=ChangeFillElementColor(fillAttr,targetColor,fillColorMode);
                    if(fillElementColor != undefined && fillElementColor != 'none')                          
                      { 
                        styleElement[styleCount].attr['fill']='#'+fillElementColor;
                      }
            }var styleAtt=styleElement[styleCount].children;
            for(var t=0; l=styleAtt.length,t<l;t++)
             {
                 sourceAttr= styleAtt[t].attr['style'];
                 var convertedStyleColor;
                if(sourceAttr != 'none')
                {
                    if(fillColorMode.toLowerCase()==="hollow")
                     {
                            //get here transparent color
                           convertedStyleColor=ConvertStringToColor(targetColor);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                            // Extract the style value and apply color accordingly gievn in tag color
                            sourceAttr= GetColor(sourceAttr)
                            convertedStyleColor=  GetUpdatedTargetColor(sourceAttr,targetColor,fillColorMode);
                     }                         
                     if(fillColorMode.toLowerCase()!=="original")
                     {
                        styleAtt[t].attr['style']='stop-color:#'+convertedStyleColor;
                     }
                }

            }//end of for

        }//end of for
      } //end of else      
    }//end of for

    //get filename here
    var newFileName= [] ;
    newFileName[0]=filePath;
    var arr=newFileName[0].split('\\');
    //ger the file name from given path 
    var  fileName = 'ReColored' + arr[arr.length-1];
    //save here new svg file with target color
    fileStream.writeFileSync(fileName, doc);//STT_FS_WRITE
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? An error stacktrace?

Comment: I have updated my Question.
The error I get is 
=======> SCRIPT5009: 'fileStream' is undefined ---- when I execute the script in browser
------------- its in the statement marked as STT_FS_WRITE
------------- coz in final bundle.js the declaration filestream = require('fs') is removed

Please let me know how could I achieve my result of writing the file content wiuth changed colr\shade to another file.

Comment: Also let me know if we can implement it in any other way ===>
like ajax calling on a node.js server
so that the functionality can be implemented from a browser.